# HTTP Status 404 - Not Found in Spring 3.2.7

Tags: spring

I am using Spring 3.2.7, I have Login.jsp file which takes the input and should display the output on hello.jsp, it takes the input but does not show an output instead it throws an error as `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found`. Here is the code:

```java
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if (password.equals("admin")) {
            String message = "Hello " + name;
            return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("errorpage", "message", "Sorry Username or Password Error");
        }
    }
}
```

**Dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="mypack" />

  <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
    p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

After observing  your Dispatcher-servlet.xml, I can see you are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`
Your Updated code will look like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">                                            

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
        <context:component-scan base-package="mypack" />
        <bean id="viewResolver"   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
        p:suffix=".jsp" />
        </beans>
```

**Explanation**

> `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` means that you can define spring beans
>   dependencies without actually having to specify a bunch of elements in
>   xml or implement an interface or extend a base class.Means @Controller
>   tells spring that the the class specified contains methods that will
>   handle http requests without you having to implement the Controller
>   interface or extend a subclass that implements controller.
>
> `<context:component-scan base-package="mypack />` tells spring that it
>   should search the class path for all the classes under `mypack` and
>   look at each class to see if it has a @Controller, or @Repository, or
>   @Service, or @Component and if it does then Spring will register the
>   class with the bean factory as if you have defined in  in the xml configuration files

Comment: Thank you so much but now I'm getting this error "In-place deployment at C:\Users\Dibya\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Spring2\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\Dibya\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Spring2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)". I'm using Netbeans 8.0 and jdk 8

Comment: first of all ,please instate of adding an answer  Edit your question add extra details .

Comment: and please attach  web.xml also

Answer (score 0):

> No, I made changes in Dispatcher-servlet.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
">

<context:component-scan base-package="mypack" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>

still am getting an error as "Status 404 - Not Found" when i submit the form.

Form:

<form action="hello.htm" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

**Here is the Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```